# Data driven currency code on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.Net MVC 5. I have the following ViewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Shipping Cost")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Shipping Currency")]
public Currency ShippingCurrency { get; set; }
```

ShippingCurrency is an enum that looks like this:

```
public enum Currency
{
    GBP,
    USD,
    CAD,
    AUD
}
```

When I view the details of a ViewModel, I want to see the Shipping Cost with the relevant currency symbol next to it, but I want to do this from my ViewModel, and not the Razor view. So in the View, I want to see:

```
200 GBP
180 USD
320 CAD
```

Is there a way to get that format via a Data Attributes on the ViewModel?

Comment: Short answer is no, because `Attributes` are metadata and their values must be know at compile time

Comment: So printing the `ShippingCost` and the `ShippingCurrency` in Razor is the only way?

Comment: You could have a property in your model which formats the result if this is just for display purposes - e.g. `public string FormatedAmount { get { return string.Format("{0:#.#} {1}", ShippingCost, ShippingCurrency.ToString()); }}`

Comment: Good thinking, can you please write an answer so that I mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using an `Attribute` since attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time.

Instead, you can include a read-only property in your view model to return the formatted value, for example

```
public string FormattedAmount
{
    get { return string.Format("{0:#.#} {1}", ShippingCost, ShippingCurrency); }
}
```

and in the view

```
<span>@Model.FormattedAmount</span>
```

Alternatively you could just combine the vales of both properties in the view

```
<span>@DisplayFor(m => m.ShippingCost)</span><span>@Model.ShippingCurrency </span>
```